# Gnome 3.32 in Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: gnome-shell, 18.10

Will gnome shell 3.32 be back ported to 18.10? I'm interested to see if the wayland support is better (since this is the only way I can realistically use two 4K monitors of different sizes).

I've looked around and haven't managed to find a way to try it out yet (though my google fu may be lacking).

I see that it will be in 19.04, but would really like to try it out now if I can.

Ta
Peter.

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 reaches feature-freeze within a week so its release approaches.  Usually backports are only performed for LTS releases, after all why backport to a normal release when they will release-upgrade to the next release in a few months. I'd say extremely unlikely officially, so unless you use a PPA (which could possibly complicate the coming release-upgrade) I'd say no.

Comment: @user535733 Gnome 3.32 *will* be in Ubuntu 19.04 — only gnome-software will stay on 3.30!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 19.04 reaches feature-freeze within a week so its release approaches. Usually backports are only performed for LTS releases, after all why backport to a normal release when they will release-upgrade to the next release in a few months. I'd say extremely unlikely officially, so unless you use a PPA (which could possibly complicate the coming release-upgrade) I'd say no

The primary reason is it's not worth the effort. GNOME 3.32 requires you run the GTK+ [software] stack 3.32 as well, meaning most of the software will need changing, turning your machine into in effect 19.04 (with a 18.10 kernel).  It's a lot of work which requires a lot of testing just to get it a few weeks early...  Ubuntu is based on releases, and minimal packages get backported as it requires more devs, more testers than exist.

fyi:  *I'm running 19.04 now, and have been for some months now.  If you want to run it now, you can.  It's currently a development release so you won't get support here (but irc ubuntu+1 is still an option) and there is a greater chance of issues, but if you want to try it - give the latest daily ISO a spin?  (and if you want to help, record it on http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/ so it's recorded as a QA (quality assurance) test.  Daily ISO's can be run in live mode if you just want to try it.  Downloads come from http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/*

Comment: Just ran it.. its fast... i'll record it and add some notes... wayland seems to work OK too once you work out how to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

Without having the facts and figures, I am pretty sure it won't. It never happened before. Yet wait about two months, and Ubuntu 19.04 will ship with Gnome 3.32.